# How can we restart an interrupted Gaussian job?

Tags: gaussian

I started to optimise a protein. But due to a power failure the process terminated before completion. So I need to restart my calculation. There were several suggestions on using `opt=restart`. I tried that but it did not work. What I did was, saved the interrupted Gaussian output as a new input file. Then opened the new input file in Gaussian09 and kept everything above coordinates section as it was except **opt** in the route section. I changed **opt** in to **opt=restart** and gave the run but this did not work.
Can anyone please tell me what is the mistake? Or is my method wrong?
[Link to the gaussian files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14hV4kxh_hwFZbdt4y1eUFuGhGq7hWgc0?usp=share_link)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62459710#62459710).

Comment: In the future, we would rather not create a new chat room whenever the comments on a question/answer get long. We have tended to take the approach of moving comments to an existing room as described in [this meta post](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/preserving-comments-and-chat-integration). I'm going to move the comments to the Gaussian chat room and redirect the created chat link.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5 and modify the question accordingly (if you still want it open). @Tyberius the chat indicates that a "new" error arose, do you think the original question has an answer? PriZarah you can answer too!